# Successive clicks failing- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a weird problem with this javascript (ldelim and rdelim are for curly braces when using smarty)

```
$('#bouton').on('click',function() {ldelim}
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(url,data,function(callback_data){ldelim}
                  ....
       {rdelim});
{rdelim});
```

this script will reveal a div tag ('#thisdiv') that was invisible. Then I added

```
$('#thisdiv').on('click',function() {ldelim}
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post(url,data,function(callback_data){ldelim}
                      ....
           {rdelim});
{rdelim});
```

But nothing is happening on the click on '#thisdiv' (even if I suppress anything in the click function on '#thisdiv' and put an alert message). Someone could help ?

Edit : before the first call there is , after the first call the class 'invisible' us removed (class 'invisible' is a display none class)

Comment: Are you replacing the element when you get the response from the AJAX call? For example `$('#thisdiv').replace(data);` or the parent element etc?

Comment: No in fact, before the first call there is <div id="this div" class="invisible">, after the first call the class 'invisible' us removed

Comment: Browser don't warns about script syntax errors? And #thisdiv have a well-defined height (i.e. there is no float elements inside without clearfix)?

Comment: @tassoevan No I got none, where should I see more in depth in my console to check for errors ?

Comment: @Newben I think that your browser console should warn if syntax error was occuring. What about #thisdiv? It's has correct size? And a stupid question, your div has the id "thisdiv" or "this div"?

Comment: Yes everything is all right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#thisdiv` does not exist when this code runs - so it cannot attach the event. You need to delegate higher up the document. For example:

```
$(document).on('click','#thisdiv',function(){...});
```

or if there is a parent element that is there on load, you could use this as the anchor:

```
$('#theparent').on('click','#thisdiv',function(){...});
```

[`jquery.on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: before the first call there is <div id="this div" class="invisible">, after the first call the class 'invisible' us removed (I am going to edit my question). So your solution is still not working

Comment: @Newben - well, the simple example you describe (reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/rMHpm/) works as expected. So there's something you're still not telling us about your code. I dont see anywhere in your example where the class `invisible` is removed.

Comment: In fact, I think indeed the problem comes from #thisdiv is a new element that was not in the 'first loading page'. The problem now is that evenb if I take any 'div', $(document).on('#anydiv','click',... triggers nothing ...

Comment: @Newben - You've lost me... what is `#anydiv` now?

Comment: It means I took any div in my code, and  $(document).on triggers nothing. I tried in my console  $(document).on('#anydiv','click', function(){

    alert('hello');

    }); and I have no output when clicking. But $('#anydiv').on('click', function(){

    alert('hello');

    }); indeed alerts 'hello' ??

Comment: @Newben - ah I see. This is my mistake, I got the order of parameters the wrong way round. It should be `$(document).on('click','#thisdiv',function(){...});`. I'll update this answer

Comment: Thank you it worked !Interesting, could you explain just a little bit why the newly created divs get called by this method and could not be detected by a common click call ?

Comment: @Newben - no. That's what documentation is for. Ive linked in the answer to the relevant page.